# Search in hierarchy tree to get tree with only result node

Tags: c#, nested, hierarchy

I have hierarchy tree, each element has a list of children and so on.
This is the class:

```
public class HierarchyItem
{
    public int? HierarchyID { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public List<HierarchyItem> children { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }        
}
```

I am trying to search for all the nodes that their label contains my search term.

I already managed to get the nodes that match my search term.
In addition i created a recursion to get all the parents (until the top node) for every node that match my search term.

The problem is that in this way i get a reverse tree:
Every children has parent that has parent and so on instead of getting parent with children that has a children and so on.

Any Idea? How to act?
I am not sure it will help, but this is the relevant code.

```
 HierarchyItem result = new HierarchyItem();

            var fullHierarchies = _entities.Hierarchies.Where(p => !p.Deleted).ToList();
            var hierarchiesResult = _entities.Hierarchies.Where(p => !p.Deleted && p.Name.Contains(searchTerm)).ToList();

            List<HierarchyItemWithParentAsHierarchyItem> itemsWithTrees = new List<HierarchyItemWithParentAsHierarchyItem>();

             var hierarchyTop = new HierarchyItemWithParentAsHierarchyItem
             {
                 HierarchyID = null,
                 label = "Organization",
                 Code = "0",
                 Path = string.Empty,
                 Level = 0,
                 Parent = null
             };

             foreach (var item in hierarchiesResult)
             {
                 var hierarchy = new HierarchyItemWithParentAsHierarchyItem
                 {
                     HierarchyID = item.HierarchyID,
                     label = item.Name,
                     Code = item.Code,
                     Path = string.Empty,
                     Level = item.Level.Value,
                 };
                 hierarchy.Parent.Add(GetParent(fullHierarchies, item, hierarchyTop));

                 itemsWithTrees.Add(hierarchy);
             }


private HierarchyItemWithParentAsHierarchyItem GetParent(List<CloudEntities.Hierarchy> fullHierarchies, CloudEntities.Hierarchy item, HierarchyItemWithParentAsHierarchyItem hierarchyTop)
    {
        try
        {
            HierarchyItemWithParentAsHierarchyItem tempHierarchyItem;
            CloudEntities.Hierarchy tempHierarchy = fullHierarchies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.HierarchyID == item.ParentID);

            if (tempHierarchy == null)
                return hierarchyTop;
            else
            {
                tempHierarchyItem = new HierarchyItemWithParentAsHierarchyItem()
                {
                    HierarchyID = tempHierarchy.HierarchyID,
                    label = tempHierarchy.Name,
                    Code = tempHierarchy.Code,
                    Path = string.Empty,
                    Level = tempHierarchy.Level.Value
                };
                tempHierarchyItem.Parent.Add(GetParent(fullHierarchies, tempHierarchy, hierarchyTop));
            }

            return tempHierarchyItem;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your current code? It's hard to debug a non-existing code.

Comment: yes, sure. but its not about the debug, its just about an idea how to implement this. i will edit my questions. thanks